# LWC onunload but for inter-app navigation

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have onunload wired so when the user clicks the the refresh button on the browser, the user is prompted asking if they want to cancel...

```
    constructor() {
        super();
        window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {
            if(this.hasUnsavedChanges === true) {
                // Cancel the event as stated by the standard.
                event.preventDefault();
                // Chrome requires returnValue to be set.
                event.returnValue = 'sample value';
            }
        });
    }
```

However, the user does not get prompted if they press the back button, and I don't know how to prompt the user when they simply navigate to another page inside the community site.

Basically I want to alert the user anytime there are changes that are unsaved and they take an action that would take them away from that component.  I have read about using onblur, but I am not sure how to wire it up from inside the component.  In other words I want the component itself to fire the alert when the page is being navigated away and prevent the navigation if there are unsaved changes and the user selects the cancel option.

Thanks.

Comment: Recommended way would be to wrap LWC component in Aura, then you can use [lightning:unsavedChanges](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:unsavedChanges) base component

Comment: just curious, did you try adding the eventListener in the connectedCallback ? beforeunload should work in lwc too

Comment: would I add window.addEventListener in connectedCallback or what exactly? I am not sure what you mean.